# Sorting with a twist

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array of six items (structs that represent a thing):

```
thing[] = new thing{thing1,thing2,thing3,thing4,thing5,thing6};
```

I have another variable that I use for a switch. This tells me which "thing" should be in the first position.

```
ENUM positionDesignation {first=0,second=1 ...sixth=5} 
//declared a little different.
```

When a user selects a different position, say 3, then the "things" should be sorted by:

1. `thing3`
2. `thing4`
3. `thing5`
4. `thing1`
5. `thing2`

I have this figured out. The problem is that each "thing" also has a property of `status`. If `status` is `broken`, then I need to push it to the end and adjust.

**Example:** `thing4` is `broken` and `thing1` is `first`

```
thing = {
  thing1.first,
  thing2.second,
  thing3.third,
  thing4.sixth,
  thing5.fourth,
  thing6.fifth
};
```

Does this make sense?

My first ordering looks like this:

```
public void setRotationOrder() {
    Thing[] things = {
        getThing1(),
        getThing2(),
        getThing3(),
        getThing4(),
        getThing5(),
        getThing6()
    };

    int[] wheel = new int[6];
    int idx = getPrimary().getOrdinal();

    idx = (idx == 0) ? 5 : idx - 1;

    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        wheel[idx] = i;
        Thing[i].setState(Rotation6Designation.make(idx));
        idx = (idx == 0) ? 5 : idx - 1;
    }
}
```

The second part looks like this:

```
int lastIndex = 5;
int cnt = 0;
int thingPos = 0;

for (int i=5;i>=0;i--) {
    // Check thing at idx. If out of service, put it at the end.
    thingPos = wheel[i];

    if (things[thingPos].getStatus().equals(AlarmShutdown) ||
            things[thingPos].getStatus().equals(MaintenanceShutdown)) {
        if (i == lastIndex) {
            things[thingPos].setState(Rotation6Designation.make(lastIndex));
            lastIndex--;
            continue;
        }

        int tmpThingPos = thingPos;
        thingPos++;

        while (true) {
            things[thingPos].setState(things[thingPos + 1].getState());
            thingPos++;

            if (thingPos == lastIndex) {
                things[thingPos].setState(Rotation6Designation.make(tmpThingPos));
            }

            lastIndex--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the **Thing** variables have some kind of unique value that is equivalent to their number you could use to compare to each other?

Maybe you could use a specific **Comparator** instance to use [*List's sort() method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Yes they do. They have an enum for name/designation. So it would be like thing[n].getDesignation.getOrdinal()

Comment: Problem is that I need to assign them values (ENUM values) so that they are in order that way. So, their respective rotation order property (ENUM) reflects what part of the order they are in,. Also, I have to adjust the order if they are out of service.

Comment: Well, then I don't think I can't be of any help, sorry and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems as though I could easily check both ends of the array. I basically started at the index of the "primary" selector. Once I got this, I offset the idxBack. I then looped and reduced the back index and increased the front index (idxBack). After checking conditions, it was easily adjusted. This drove me nuts for a long time.

```
 public void setRotationOrder(){
  Thing[] things = {getThing1(),getThing2(),getThing3(),getThing4(),getThing5(),getThing6()};
  int idxFront = getPrimary().getOrdinal(); //3
  int idxBack =(idxFront==0)?5:idxFront-1; //2

  int lastIndex =5;
  int firstIndex=0;
  for (int i =5 ;i>=0 ;i--){
    System.out.println("Last index: "+lastIndex+", First index: "+firstIndex);
    System.out.println("idxBack: "+idxBack+", idxFront: "+idxFront);
    //*********************NEW*******************************/

    if (things[idxBack].getStatus().equals(Mode.AlarmShutdown) ||
            things[idxBack].getStatus().equals(Mode.MaintenanceShutdown)) {
      things[idxBack].setState(RotationDesignation.make(lastIndex));
      System.out.println( "Broken: things["+idxBack+"] "+things[idxBack].getState());
      System.out.println( "things["+idxBack+"] "+things[idxBack].getStatus());
      lastIndex--;
    }
    if (!things[idxFront].getStatus().equals(Mode.AlarmShutdown) &&
            !things[idxFront].getStatus().equals(Mode.MaintenanceShutdown)) {
      things[idxFront].setState(RotationDesignation.make(firstIndex));
      System.out.println( "Not Broken: things["+idxFront+"] "+things[idxFront].getState());
      firstIndex++;

    }
    idxFront=(idxFront==5)?0:idxFront+1;
    idxBack=(idxBack==0)?5:idxBack-1;
  }
```